# What shall I do if the requirement of a method (with lot of tests already) changed?

Tags: testing, tdd

I have some questions about the `TDD`(test driven development): a method has already have some tests, and the requirement changes, what should I do?

Say there is a Taximeter, which has a init fare `$6` for `2km`, and then `$0.8` for each extra kilometer, and `$0.25` for every waiting minute. I have writen several tests like this:

```
public class TaximeterTest {
    @Test public void testInitFare() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().calcuate(2), 6.0, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test3km() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().calcuate(3), 6.8, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test8km() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().calcuate(8), 9.2, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test3kmWaiting1Minute() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().calcuate(3, 1), 7.05, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test8kmWaiting10Minutes() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().calcuate(8, 10), 11.7, 0.00001);
    }
}
```

Then the requirement changes: the Taximeter should round off the price, so the `3km`, it should be `$7`, and for `8km`, it should be `$9`.

What should I do now? I have 2 options:

### 1. Modify all affected existing tests and won't involve new methods

```
public class TaximeterTest {
    @Test public void testInitFare() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().calcuate(2), 6.0, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test3km() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().calcuate(3), 7.0 /*rounded*/, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test8km() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().calcuate(8), 9.0 /*rounded*/, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test3kmWaiting1Minute() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().calcuate(3, 1), 7.0 /*rounded*/, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test8kmWaiting10Minutes() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().calcuate(8, 10), 12.0 /*rounded*/, 0.00001);
    }
}
```

Seems work OK if there are only a few tests, but if there rules are complex enough, maybe there dozens of tests need to be changed.

I also want to know the real fare before rounding, I don't feel safe if I only know the rounded price.

So I'm considering the option `2`

### 2. add concepts of `internalPrice` and `finalPrice`

The `internalPrice` is the price before rounding, and the `finalPrice` is rounded of `internalPrice`.

First I need to rename the `calculate` method to `internalPrice`, and the class name of the test is changing to `TaximeterInternalPriceTest`, but all the data in the tests are not changed:

```
public class TaximeterInternalPriceTest {
    @Test public void testInitFare() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().internalPrice(2), 6.0, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test3km() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().internalPrice(3), 6.8, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test8km() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().internalPrice(8), 9.2, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test3kmWaiting1Minute() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().internalPrice(3, 1), 7.05, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test8kmWaiting10Minutes() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().internalPrice(8, 10), 11.7, 0.00001);
    }
}
```

Then create new tests for `finalPrice`:

```
public class TaximeterFinalPriceTest {
    @Test public void testInitFare() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().finalPrice(2), 6.0, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test3kmWaiting1Minute() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().finalPrice(3, 1), 7.0 /*rounded*/, 0.00001);
    }
    @Test public void test8kmWaiting10Minutes() {
        assertEquals(new Taximeter().finalPrice(8, 10), 12.0 /*rounded*/, 0.00001);
    }
}
```

But the problem is the `internalPrice` is actually only used in `finalPrice` and should be private, but it have be non-private if I want to test it:

```
double internalPrice(int km, int waitingMinutes)
public double finalPrice(int km, int waitingMinutes)
```

I'm puzzled now and not sure which option is better, or there is even better options. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You could break the object up. For example:

- One object that takes a distance, and returns a price for the given distance.
- One object that takes wait time and returns the price for the wait.
- One is a Taximeter that takes each of the rules and combines them and returns the final price.

The price per distance object can be tested in isolation which out worrying about changes in the logic for either wait time, or final price.
The price per wait object can be tested in isolation which out worrying about changes in the logic for either distance, or final price.
The Taximeter can be tested using stubs so that changes to rules can happen without effecting its unit tests.